# Launch program in python and later a python script that monitors the output files generated by the program

Tags: python

I want to launch a program from python, in this case abaqus (a finite element analysis software), using:

```
os.system('abaqus job=' + JobName + ' user=' + UELname + ' interactive')
```

After say 5 minutes running the program I want to execute a python script that monitors some output files generated by abaqus. If a certain condition is met than the python script will terminate the abaqus job. There's a catch here. To read the output files I need to run the python script from abaqus:

```
os.system('abaqus cae noGUI=results2.py')
```

My question is this:

Can I do this simply by:

```
os.system('abaqus job=' + JobName + ' user=' + UELname + ' interactive')
time.sleep(300)
os.system('abaqus cae noGUI=results2.py')
```

I know that using `interactive` key makes ths system wait for the abaqus job to finish before doing other stuff. Therefore, I asssume this is not as simple as I'd like it to be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module?

Answer (score 1):

Logic seems fine, i would suggest you to use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), instead of os.system. Since you are calling commands, you can run all these commands at once like this

```
cmdToRun = '\'abaqus job=\' + JobName + \' user=\' + UELname + \' interactive\' ; sleep 300; abaqus cae noGUI=results2.py'
```